# Admob - Ad failed to load : 3

Tags: android, admob

Admob was working perfectly fine at the beginning. But since around one month I'm only receiving an Error:

> Ad failed to load : 3

I've already tried everything like changing packagename, creating new adunits/admob app... I've also tried it on multiple real devices so there is nothing wrong with my device. When using

```
.addTestDevice()
```

it's working fine.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, looking for an explanation..

Answer (score 0):

Code 3 goes for ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL:

```
"The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory."
```

If you are filtering ads to comply with family/privacy/kids protection policies then you should expect a low fill rate, specially while you are on the developing phase. However your fill rate might improve if your app becomes famous.

Comment: I did not add any limitations to the adunit settings. What you said lastly is propably correctly. I think my app needs more requests to receive ads more frequently.